# Toshiba Satellite L75 won't boot up

Tags: boot

I turn on my Toshiba Satellite L75 and after the Toshiba... Leading Innovation screen it goes right into a Black screen with a light gray-blue box that says "Enter Password"
I have no password and nothing works.
Anything you put in you get a red box that says 
"Verify Error!!
Press ENTER to continue"
After 3 times, the computer automatically shuts off.

Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: Leave it blank and hit enter, what does it do?

Comment: I get a red box saying  "verify error!! Press ENTER to continue" and the word Enter is in a blue rectangle

Comment: If I do it 3 times in a row it says "Verify error... System is shutting down"

Comment: @Mark It is asking for the BIOS password...details in the answer...did you try any of those ?

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a Toshiba satellite L755(2011 and it still works like new).
Well and the same thing happened to me once, I accidentally set up the BIOS password(it was through a program in windows somehow), and I used to get the same box you described, you can try the following:

- Reset the CMOS
- Use a Backdoor Password :  An example of a Toshiba backdoor password is, unsurprisingly, "Toshiba." When the BIOS prompts you to enter a password, entering "Toshiba" may allow you to access your PC and clear the old BIOS password. Another option is to hold the left "Shift" key down while booting.Try searching for Toshiba BIOS master reset passwords or backdoor password.

Check out this link: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/toshiba-satellite-bios-password-removal.

If this does not work, then you might have to reset your BIOS by opening up your laptop and short circuiting the jumpers, usually located just beneath the RAM.Search for videos on youtube like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siSoOXkNSgw

Good Luck.